# Call to endpoint fails returns string(69) "Error: This method supports only xml ExceptionType: System.Exception"

Tags: php, curl, endpoint

I am trying to make this code return the data at the endpoint but it returns this error `string(69) "Error: This method supports only XML ExceptionType: System. Exception"`. I have tried checking what it means but couldn't figure it out.

The code is broken into 2 parts, the first part which dumps the `$result` array variable works well. The second dump of `$resResult` is what's giving the problem. This means that call to the first endpoint works well but calling the second keeps failing.

Code PHP
<?php

```
$username = '73ec71d0a809/Markettrendsintl';
$password = 'Market@123';
$surveyID = '47f2-bfe4-db0eb01d1049';
$endpoint = 'https://api.dooblo.net/newapi/SurveyInterviewIDs?surveyIDs='.$surveyID;

$credentials = base64_encode("$username:$password");

$headers = [];
$headers[] = "Authorization: Basic {$credentials}";
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';

$headers1 = [];
$headers1[] = "Authorization: Basic {$credentials}";
$headers1[] = 'Content-Type: text/xml';
$headers1[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result[] = curl_exec($ch);

/*---------New Code -----------------*/
$counter = 0;
$interviewIdsInCurPack = '';
for ($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++) { 
  $interviewIdsInCurPack = sprintf("{0},{1}", $interviewIdsInCurPack, $result[$i]);
  $counter += 1;
  $lastInterviewID = $i==$result[$i];

  if ($counter == 99 || $lastInterviewID) {
      $interviewIdsInCurPack = substr_replace($interviewIdsInCurPack, 0, 1);
                 $urlInterviewData = sprintf("https://api.dooblo.net/newapi/SurveyInterviewData?subjectIDs={0}&surveyID={1}&onlyHeaders=false&includeNulls=false", $interviewIdsInCurPack, $surveyID);
                 // print($urlInterviewData);

                  $sender = curl_init();

                  curl_setopt($sender, CURLOPT_URL, $urlInterviewData);
                  curl_setopt($sender, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                  curl_setopt($sender, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
                  curl_setopt($sender, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers1);

                  $resResult = curl_exec($sender);
                   var_dump($resResult);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://support.dooblo.net/hc/en-us/articles/208294645-How-To-Use-The-SurveyToGo-REST-API) of Dooblo:

> However, please keep in mind that for some operations that return either interview data or survey data in them, only XML will be supported as an output format. If you try to call these with JSON as format you will receive an error: “Error: This method supports only xml” from the API

That last part is exactly your error message. According to their [REST API example](https://support.dooblo.net/hc/en-us/articles/360000521885-REST-API-How-to-retrieve-the-interview-data-of-a-survey) code you can set the desired output-format using the [HTTP Accept header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept):

> client.AddDefaultHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
>
> client.AddDefaultHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");

They are using a different client there, within PHP you do that as followed:

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: text/html',
    'Accept-Charset: utf-8'
));
```